# Samsung Focus hanging when charging

Tags: charging, samsung-focus

Today my Samsung Focus started to hang every time I plug it on USB (charger or PC).

It starts to charging about 5 seconds and boot. If I remove the cable it works again.

I already tried to remove and put the battery again but didn't solve.

The only different thing I did today was use some Pranks features of WPH Tweaks (Like Wireless charge and AC Power) but change to default again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was easier than I thought. Just made a Hard Reset:

Samsung Focus will be returned to its original state with full data wipe. 
Dial ##634# from the phone pad press the call button when the diagnostic screen appears type *2767*3855# to perform a full restore.